# Plectrum Guitar music-sheet

Tags: sheet-music, acoustic-guitar, accidentals

The Roman numeral at the top is fret number and the number written next to the grace notes is the finger number which is 1 (index) should I be sliding from 5th fret to 7th using my index which would be F# and B or should I be hammering to G and B following the key signature.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your doubt comes from, but what you clearly have to do is slide from the 5th fret to the 7th fret on the B and E strings. Maybe you're surprised by the sharp which is a [courtesy accidental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_(music)#Courtesy_accidentals) reminding you that you should play an F# (because there was an F natural in the previous bar).

Comment: Those courtesy accidentals sometimes get me going. There are other places  where they could have been used, but aren't. Question - bar 22. 2nd note - B what? That's where an accidental may have been useful...

Comment: @Tim: There are different conventions concerning courtesy accidentals, but in this case, referring to bar 22, the b flat in bar 21 had already been turned into a b in the same bar, so there's nothing to remind the player of.